# Can I create a cluster whose nodes are connected via HTTP by kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a cluster whose nodes are connected via HTTP(not HTTPS).
Is it possible to create the cluster with kubeadm?
I didn't see any command can do it in the document of kubeadm.
If it is impossible, can I change a cluster over HTTPS to one over HTTP?

Comment: Could you specify your needs? You want to install kubeadm not using https protocol based on docs, exact this command: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl?
You dont want secured connection between nodes? Or you want to achieve something else?

Comment: @PjoterS Yes, I don't need the secured connection(HTTPS) because I am developing a prototype, and I found the operations of HTTPS take a lot of time. I don't care the security currently, so I just need HTTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

Currently as best practices is to make your cluster secure as much as possible and kubernetes provides [many ways to do it](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/18/11-ways-not-to-get-hacked/).

However if you will have isolated environment you can try to set flags `--insecure-port` to set port which will be insecure bounded and `--insecure-bind-address` which will set an address to insecure port. Details about them can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/#api-server-ports-and-ips).

For example `insecure-bind-address: "0.0.0.0" insecure-port: "8080"` should allow access to the unauthenticated api endpoint running on port 8080.

You can also check if [vulnerability scenarios](https://github.com/raesene/kind-of-insecure) which are based on [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) contains something interesting for your testing.

Comment: I tried to use configuration file to carry these flags, which are "--insecure-port" and "--kubelet-https ", when I use kubeadm. However, the kubeadm seems not integrate the whole system well. The generated YAML files always use https, e.g. , https://MYIP:8080

Comment: I was not able to find anything else about this in Kubernetes documentation. As one of the Values of Kubernetes is to make is as much secure as possible I think this is not possible to completely turn off HTTPS in Kubeadm.